# SharePoint 2010 Discussion Board - Last Updated column no longer populated

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We're having a sudden issue where new discussion board posts are not showing up on the default view.  I found the reason why was because the Last Updated column is no longer being updated (it's blank).

Unsure of the reason why.  As a work around, I changed the view to sort by created date.  But this bandaid won't work for long.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Did the column definition change?

Comment: I went into list settings and saw that "Last Updated" is not a configurable column. Does that sound right?  The only place i see it is in the view settings.

Comment: It *shouldn't* be configurable :D

Comment: I'm tempted to just wipe out the entire board and recreate... this is just driving me nuts!